# Как с помощью регулярных выражений заменить цифры в строке на буквы? Язык PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить вопрос по замене в строке цифр в определенном порядке?

Короче есть вот такая строка

$number = '7586 780045';

Надо заменить символы под номером в строке 3, 4,6,7,8 что бы получилась вот такая строка '75АА ААА045'.
При этом в строке может идти пробел 5 символом, а может и не идти.

Я только познаю азы этих движух и поэтому сам не досямкал, как это можно сделать.

Или может есть более простое решение.

Помогите пожалуйста. За ранее спасибо.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/jei3qP/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем и целом, вам нужно выделить группы, которые останутся на своих местах. То есть первые две цифры, вероятный пробел, и последние 3. Дотом подставите их в нужные места через ссылки `$N`

```
$txt = "7586 780045";    
echo preg_replace("/(\d\d)\d\d(\s?)\d{3}(\d+)/", '$1AA$2AAA$3', $txt);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Так сработало. А я и не знал что так можно. :)